# Is the Amazon Drive API still closed for new developers?

Tags: amazon-drive

For a new project i need to reorganize a huge amazon cloud drive. There is no way i can do it manually and wanted to use the API. It appears that some one needs to be whitelisted is there another easier way for personal use?

Comment: They really don't want you using it for anything but storing personal photos at this point. They even renamed the service Amazon Photos. If you have a huge amount of data on there the best thing you can do at this point is sync all that data to another service and quit using Amazon Drive.

Comment: I would also add, Amazon is actively revoking API access to Amazon Drive, for example: https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Backup/Discontinued_access_to_Amazon_Drive They aren't going to be handing out API access to anyone new at this point.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. They really want to get rid of customers i guess